# sed: read whole file into pattern space without failing on single-line input

Tags: sed, newlines

Reading a whole file into pattern space is useful for substituting newlines, &c.
and there are many instances advising the following:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba; [commands...]'
```

However, it fails if the input contains only one line.

As an example, with two line input, every line is subjected to the substitution command:

```
$ echo $'abc\ncat' | sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/a/xxx/g'
xxxbc
cxxxt
```

But, with single line input, *no* substitution is performed:

```
$ echo 'abc' | sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/a/xxx/g'
abc
```

How does one write a `sed` command to read all the input in at once and not have this problem?

Comment: I edited your question so that it contains an actual question.  You may wait for other answers if you like but do eventually mark the best answer as accepted (See the pipe button at left of the answer, right below the up-down arrow buttons).

Comment: @John1024 Thanks, good to have an example. Finding this kind of thing tends to remind me that "everything is wrong" but I'm glad some of us don't give up. :}

Comment: There's a third option! Use GNU's `sed -z` option. If your file doesn't have null, it will read until the end of file! Found from this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30049447/582917

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are all kinds of reasons why reading a whole file into pattern space can go wrong. The logic problem in the question surrounding the last line is a common one. It is related to `sed`'s line cycle - when there are no more lines and `sed` encounters EOF it is through - it quits processing. And so if you are on the last line and you instruct `sed` to get another it's going to stop right there and do no more.

That said, if you really need to read a whole file into pattern space, then it is probably worth considering another tool anyway. The fact is, `sed` is eponymously the *stream* editor - it is designed to work a line - or a logical data block - at a time.

There are many similar tools that are better equipped to handle full file blocks. `ed` and `ex`, for example, can do much of what `sed` can do and with similar syntax - and much else besides - but rather than operating only on an input stream while transforming it to output as `sed` does, they also maintain temporary backup files in the file-system. Their work is buffered to disk as needed, and they do not quit abruptly at end of file *(and tend to implode a lot less often under buffer strain)*. Moreover they offer many useful functions which `sed` does not - of the sort that simply do not make sense in a stream context - like line marks, undo, named buffers, join, and more.

`sed`'s primary strength is its ability to process data as soon as it reads it - quickly, efficiently, and in stream. When you slurp a file you throw that away *and* you tend to run into edge case difficulties like the last line problem you mention, and buffer overruns, and abysmal performance - as the data it parses grows in length a regexp engine's processing time when enumerating matches increases *exponentially*.

Regarding that last point, by the way: while I understand the example `s/a/A/g` case is very likely just a naive example and is probably not the actual script you want to gather in an input for, you might might find it worth your while to familiarize yourself with `y///`. If you often find yourself `g`lobally substituting a single character for another, then `y` could be very useful for you. It is a transformation as opposed to a substitution and is far quicker as it does not imply a regexp. This latter point can also make it useful when attempting to preserve and repeat empty `//` addresses because it does not affect them but can be affected by them. In any case, `y/a/A/` is a more simple means of accomplishing the same - and swaps are possible as well like: `y/aA/Aa/` which would interchange all upper/lowercase as on a line for each other.

You should also note that the behavior you describe is really not what is supposed to happen anyway.

From GNU's `info sed` in the *COMMONLY REPORTED BUGS* section:

- `N` command on the last line

  - Most versions of `sed` exit without printing anything when the `N` command is issued on the last line of a file. GNU `sed` prints pattern space before exiting unless of course the `-n` command switch has been specified. This choice is by design.
  - For example, the behavior of `sed N foo bar` would depend on whether foo has an even or an odd number of lines. Or, when writing a script to read the next few lines following a pattern match, traditional implementations of `sed` would force you to write something like `/foo/{ $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N }` instead of just `/foo/{ N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N; }`.
  - In any case, the simplest workaround is to use `$d;N` in scripts that rely on the traditional behavior, or to set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable to a non-empty value.

The `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is mentioned because POSIX specifies that if `sed` encounters EOF when attempting an `N` it should quit without output, but the GNU version intentionally breaks with the standard in this case. Note also that even as the behavior is justified above the assumption is that the error case is one of stream-editing - not slurping a whole file into memory.

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) defines `N`'s behavior thus:

- `N`

  - Append the next line of input, less its terminating `\n`ewline, to the pattern space, using an embedded `\n`ewline to separate the appended material from the original material. Note that the current line number changes.
  - If no next line of input is available, the `N` command verb shall branch to the end of the script and quit without starting a new cycle or copying the pattern space to standard output.

On that note, there are some other GNU-isms demonstrated in the question - particularly the use of the `:`label, `b`ranch, and `{` function-context brackets `}`. As a rule of thumb any `sed` command which accepts an arbitrary parameter is understood to delimit at a `\n`ewline in the script. So the commands...

```
:arbitrary_label_name; ...
b to_arbitrary_label_name; ...
//{ do arbitrary list of commands } ...
```

...are all very likely to perform erratically depending on the `sed` implementation that reads them. Portably they should be written:

```
...;:arbitrary_label_name
...;b to_arbitrary_label_name
//{ do arbitrary list of commands
}
```

The same holds true for `r`, `w`, `t`, `a`, `i`, and `c` *(and possibly a few more that I'm forgetting at the moment)*. In almost every case they might also be written:

```
sed -e :arbitrary_label_name -e b\ to_arbitary_label_name -e \
    "//{ do arbitrary list of commands" -e \}
```

...where the new `-e`xecution statement stands in for the `\n`ewline delimiter. So where the GNU `info` text suggests a *traditional `sed` implementation would force you to do*:

```
/foo/{ $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N }
```

...it should rather be...

```
/foo/{ $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N; $!N
}
```

...of course, that isn't true either. Writing the script in that way is a little silly. There are much more simple means of doing the same, like:

```
printf %s\\n foo . . . . . . |
sed -ne 'H;/foo/h;x;//s/\n/&/3p;tnd
         //!g;x;$!d;:nd' -e 'l;$a\' \
     -e 'this is the last line'
```

...which prints:

```
foo
.
.
.
foo\n.\n.\n.$
.$
this is the last line
```

...because the `t`est command - like most `sed` commands - depends on the line cycle to refresh its return register and here the line cycle is permitted to do most of the work. That's another tradeoff you make when you slurp a file - the line cycle doesn't refresh ever again, and so many tests will behave abnormally.

The above command doesn't risk over-reaching input because it just does some simple tests to verify what it reads as it reads it. With `H`old all lines are appended to the hold space, but if a line matches `/foo/` it overwrites `h`old space. The buffers are next e`x`changed, and a conditional `s///`ubstitution is attempted if the contents of the buffer match the `//`last pattern addressed. In other words `//s/\n/&/3p` attempts to replace the third newline in hold space with itself and print the results *if* hold space currently matches `/foo/`. If that `t`ests successful the script branches to the `n`ot `d`elete label - which does a `l`ook and wraps up the script.

In the case that both `/foo/` and a third newline cannot be matched together in hold space though, then `//!g` will overwrite the buffer if `/foo/` is not matched, or, if it is matched, it will overwrite the buffer if a `\n`ewline is not matched *(thereby replacing `/foo/` with itself)*. This little subtle test keeps the buffer from filling up unnecessarily for long stretches of no `/foo/` and ensures the process stays snappy because the input does not pile on. Following on in a no `/foo/` or `//s/\n/&/3p` fail case the buffers are again swapped and every line but the last is there deleted.

That last - the last line `$!d` - is a simple demonstration of how a top-down `sed` script can be made to handle multiple cases easily. When your general method is to prune away unwanted cases starting with the most general and working toward the most specific then edge cases can be more easily handled because they are simply allowed to fall through to the end of the script with your other wanted data and when it all wraps you're left with only the data you want. Having to fetch such edge cases out of a closed loop can be far more difficult to do, though.

And so here's the last thing I have to say: if you must really pull in an entire file, then you can stand to do a little less work by relying on the line cycle to do it for you. Typically you would use `N`ext and `n`ext for *lookahead* - because they advance *ahead* of the line cycle. Rather than redundantly implementing a closed loop within a loop - as the `sed` line cycle is just an simple read loop anyway - if your purpose is only to gather input indiscriminately, then it is probably easier to do:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;...'
```

...which will gather the entire file or go bust trying.

---

a side note about `N` and last line behavior...

> while i do not have the tools available to me to test,
>   consider that `N` when reading and *in-place* editing
>   behaves differently if the file edited is the script file for next readthrough.

Comment: Putting the unconditional `H` first is lovely.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for your input. I can see potential benefit in keeping the line cycle, but how is it less work?

Comment: @dicktyr well, the syntax takes some shortcuts `:a;$!{N;ba}` as I mention above - it is easier to use standard form in the long run when you try to run regexps on unfamiliar systems. But that wasn't really what I meant: You implement a closed loop - you can't as easily get into the middle of that when you want to as you might instead by branching out - pruning unwanted data - and letting the cycle happen. It's like a top-down thing - everything `sed` does is a direct result of what it has just done. Maybe you see it differently - but if you try it you might find the script comes easier.

Answer (score 13):

It fails because the `N` command comes before the pattern match `$!` (not last line) and sed quits before doing any work:

> #### N
>
> Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space. **If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands**.

This can be easily fixed to work with single-line input as well (and indeed to be more clear in any case) by simply grouping the `N` and `b` commands after the pattern:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba}; [commands...]'
```

It works as follows:

1. `:a` create a label named 'a'
2. `$!` if not the last line, then
3. `N` append the next line to the pattern space (or quit if there is no next line)
   and `ba` branch (go to) label 'a'

Unfortunately, it's not portable (as it relies on GNU extensions), but the following alternative (suggested by @mikeserv) is portable:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; [commands...]'
```

Comment: I posted this here because I didn't find the information elsewhere and I wanted to make it available so others may avoid trouble with the widespread `:a;N;$!ba;`.

Comment: Thanks for posting! Remember that accepting your own answer is also fine. You just need to wait a while before the system lets you do it.

Answer (score 1):

As @mikeserv exhaustively explains N isn't suitable for this.

This fragment will accumulate the whole file and you can use it as a prefix to the rest of the script:

```
H;$!d;x;s/^\n//
```

It uses H to accumulate the file until the last line has been read

An example of use *tested with GNU sed), note the lack of trailing \n:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nc' | sed -e 'H;$!d;x;s/^\n//' -e 's/^/[/;s/$/]/'
[a
b
c]$ echo $?
0
```