# How can i convert uncertain no of line in single line record

Tags: awk

I have same question asked here in latest,but i have something different problem.
Ex:

Input file

```
******************
.WER
+ aaa bbb ccc
+ ddd eee 
******************
.SDF
+ zzz xxx yyy 
+ iii  
+ kkk lll
******************
.XCV
+ uuu vvv ggg 
+ hhh qqq
******************
```

Desired Output:

```
******************
.WER aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
******************
.SDF zzz xxx yyy iii kkk lll
******************
.XCV uuu vvv ggg hhh qqq
******************
```

So as per above i have file where no of line is no certain. It can be 2,3 or 4 and every record separated with ****************** whether it is possible to convert all lines of each record in single line? For exact no of lines i have succesfully used `paste -s -d '  \n'`.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this exact same question a few days ago? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537908/133219. Or is this homework for a class you and some other people are taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use awk, then at least with GNU awk you could do something like

```
$ gawk -vRS='\n[*]+' -F'[ ]*\n[+][ ]*' '{NF+=0; ORS=RT} 1' file
******************
.WER aaa bbb ccc ddd eee 
******************
.SDF zzz xxx yyy iii kkk lll
******************
.XCV uuu vvv ggg hhh qqq
******************
```

which simply sets appropriate record and field separators, and forces re-assembly of the record with default (single space) field separators.

Comment: Sorry for addition but it is possible to print particular column instead of whole line. Update will very helpful

Comment: @KalpeshBhoj please edit your question - or ask another. You will need to be more specific than "print particular column".

Answer (score 3):

```bash
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/ *\n+ / /;ta' -e 'P;D' testfile
******************
.WER aaa bbb ccc ddd eee 
******************
.SDF zzz xxx yyy iii kkk lll
******************
.XCV uuu vvv ggg hhh qqq
******************
```

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt holds a similar example.

- `:a` create the label 'a'
- `$!N` append the next line (and a newline) to the pattern space, IF it is not the last line ($!)
- `s/ *\n+ / /` Replace trailing spaces, the newline, the + and the space after it with a single space
- `ta` jump back to label a
- `P`rint the pattern space.  This will produce double output, because we didn't use the `-n`-option to sed,
  so now, we need to
- `D`elete the superfluous output.

Comment: Great, would you explain the code?

Comment: Well done, but you need to put explanations in for credit. It's the way it works on this site.